# Pagination on a news page not working

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Although there are 4 posts in this blog I only want three to be displayed, which is working ok http://bit.ly/sFcp4D. However when you click the next and previous buttons it would move to the next post. I am unsure as to why this isn't moving. Can anyone shed any like on this, thank you.

```
   <!--BEGIN CONTENT-->
    <article id="content">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="post post-page" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

    <div class="post-content our-news">
    <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php 

    $page = get_query_var( 'page' );

    query_posts( array('category_name' => 'Our News',  'posts_per_page' => 3, 'paged' => $page)); 

    ?>
    <ul id="news">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <li class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

                <div class="box">

                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('portfolio-thumb'); ?>
                    </a>

                </div>

                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <span><?php the_time('F jS Y') ?></span>

                <div class="entry">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>

            </li>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <div class="clear">
</ul>

        <div class="navigation">
            <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('<<', 3) ?></div>
            <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('>>', 3) ?></div>
        </div>

    <?php else : ?>

        <h2 class="center">Not Found</h2>
        <p class="center">Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.</p>

    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>




    <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'HAWK_FRONT' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); //end link page ?>

    <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'HAWK_FRONT' ), '<div class="edit-link">', '</div>' ); //end edit link ?>

</div>
<!--end post page-->
<?php else : ?>

<!--BEGIN NO POST-->
<div class="no-post">
<h2><?php esc_html_e('Not Found', 'HAWK_FRONT'); ?></h2>
<p><?php esc_html_e("Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.", 'HAWK_FRONT'); ?></p>
</div>
<!--END NO POST-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing 6 different articles, 3 on each page.